# Spell check application for websites

Tags: automated-testing, web-application

Is there a tool for checking the spelling errors, grammar and broken links in a web application completely. This application should crawl through all the pages of the site and produce a report which will show the stats. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For broken link this is best : http://www.iwebtool.com/broken_link_checker

For spelling test : http://respelt.com/

These both I have been using to suggesting you also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress there is a cool plugin called '[Broken Link Checker (WP Plugin)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/)' that can crawl all the pages and build a report for broken or redirecting urls. You can also trust some online tools like '[Broken Link Checker](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561356-broken-link-checker.aspx)' from WTH.

Answer (score 0):

More Tools

- Linkcheck - http://www.websitegoodies.com/tools/linkcheck.php
- Broken Links - http://www.linktiger.com/
- Other resources - http://freenuts.com/top-10-free-online-spell-checkers/